# Why does overflow:scroll not work in this interface?

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, webpack

Following advice on articles such as this one from CSS-Tricks (https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/overflow/), I built a two-pane UI using Bootstrap for an Angular-driven app. The two panes are intended to vertically scroll independent from one another and from the page as a whole. This behavior is working as intended in the latest release of the project, here: https://monstermancer.herokuapp.com/ (it may be necessary to shorten your browser window to see the pane scrolling in action without logging in). In case it's relevant, this version of the app uses SystemJS and Angular 2.0.0-rc5.

Recently, after I made the change to Webpack, using Angular CLI and updated the Angular version to 2.2, but while keeping all the HTML and LESS the same, that scrolling behavior no longer works. See it in "action" here: https://monster-mash.herokuapp.com/

I have a codepen up that isolates a sample view from within the app and concerns itself with *only* the scrolling behavior here: https://codepen.io/Polisurgist/pen/bBOZzm

Relevant CSS from that pen:

```
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.scroll {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar{
    display:none;
}
```

My assumption is that somehow I missed a critical bit of CSS when I moved the code from the old version to the new, though I can't place what the missing piece could be. I'm tagging angularJS and webpack on this question not because I think that either of those really *caused* the problem, but because some problem may have been introduced as collateral to me making this update.

The core question here is **What is the reason, if any, that the two panes in this interface aren't scrolling vertically?** https://monster-mash.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `#content, .row, col-sm8` are sizing the height automatically to accomodate the inner content so scroll never appears.

To resolve this and get scrolling behaviour you want, you need to make all the parent element 100%. You can **do so by adding this to your css** (add other col class to the list of selectors as neccessary):

```
html,
body,
.row,
.col-sm8,
#content{
  height:100%;
}
```

Comment: This is really helpful...I can't do _exactly_ that in my case but it tells me where to start fixing the problem. I'm still really confused why it works in one case and not the other.

Comment: @Daniel While this is a solution to the problem, it doesn't explain what CSS changed between https://monstermancer.herokuapp.com/ (working) and https://monster-mash.herokuapp.com/ (broken), during which OP made no changes to his CSS.

Comment: So, the problem was indeed the parent elements scaling to fit that content, though setting CSS rules as they are in this answer isn't workable because of how those interact with Bootstrap. What does appear to work is using `height:100vh` instead of `100%`, since that sets the height of the scrolling container based on the viewport and not the parent element. I may be missing a reason why this is not a good idea, though.

Comment: If you're using vh units just be sure to check compatibility with the browsers your project needs to support